# How to transform List into Map of List

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

I have a list with this data and I want to transform this in a Map<DateTime, List> with as variable for event (_id, title, date, active), ere is an example of data that I recover:

```json
[
   {
      "_id":8,
      "title":"Matin",
      "date":"2021-08-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   },
   {
      "_id":9,
      "title":"Après-midi",
      "date":"2021-08-04T12:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   },
   {
      "_id":11,
      "title":"Matin",
      "date":"2021-08-05T00:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   },
   {
      "_id":12,
      "title":"Après-midi",
      "date":"2021-08-05T12:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   },
   {
      "_id":6,
      "title":"Matin",
      "date":"2021-08-11T00:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   },
   {
      "_id":7,
      "title":"Après-midi",
      "date":"2021-08-11T12:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   },
   {
      "_id":4,
      "title":"Matin",
      "date":"2021-08-17T00:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   },
   {
      "_id":10,
      "title":"Matin",
      "date":"2021-08-17T00:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   }
]
```

And in each value I have a date with year, month, day and time and I would like to group the dates without taking the hour into account, what will look like this:

```json
"2021-08-04": [
{
      "_id":8,
      "title":"Matin",
      "date":"2021-08-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   },
   {
      "_id":9,
      "title":"Après-midi",
      "date":"2021-08-04T12:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   }
],
"2021-08-05": [
[
   {
      "_id":11,
      "title":"Matin",
      "date":"2021-08-05T00:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   },
   {
      "_id":12,
      "title":"Après-midi",
      "date":"2021-08-05T12:00:00.000Z",
      "active":1
   }
]
```

I try to do something with Map.fromIterable but I have some error...
If someone can help me thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I brute-forced the solution type you need. The provided solution will work for sure if the format of the date stored doesn't change.

```
void converter(var data) {
  var req={};
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var date=data[i]["date"].toString().substring(0,10);
    if(!req.containsKey(date))
      req[date]=[];
    req[date].add(data[i]);
  }
  print(req);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using flutter there is a package that can handle this of stuff.
https://pub.dev/packages/collection

you will need groupby.

i did something like that, idk if the api is still the same. Anyhow here is the snippet.

```
.map(
        (List<Appointment> appointments) {
          appointments.sort(
            (Appointment a, Appointment b) {
              if (a.appointmentdate
                  .difference(b.appointmentdate)
                  .isNegative) return -1;
              return 1;
            },
          );
          return appointments;
        },
      ).distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `data` is the `List<Map<String, Object>>` variable you listed, i.e. assuming your data is not a JSON object, I'd do:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String,Object>>> myTfData = {}
data.forEach(
    (value) {
      var myDate = value['date'] as String;
      if(myTfData.containsKey(myDate)) myTfData[myDate] = [];
      myTfData[myDate]!.add(value);
    }
  );
```

You'd obtain a `Map<String, List<Map<String,Object>>>` object as requested.

Comment: `Iterable.forEach` doesn't return a value.